# How to raise form validation if during form initialisation in django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am making a project which consists of different conferences and different talks related to them.
What I wanted to do is to check for a condition that if the conference end date is passed/expired than the current_date/today then the user can not be able to modify the title of the form fields but can edit other fields. So to check it i have added a line in my update_view function in which the parameters are the conference to which the particular proposal belong

```
if not conference.end_date < datetime.now().date():
        proposal.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
```

The above line is efficient to make a constrain but it is done silently,he will try to change the title but will not be able to do without getting any error, I want some method like form validation error method that he/she can not change the title .
and to generate the dynamic/custom form I have used

```
def __init__(self, conference, action="edit", *args, **kwargs):
```

This above line is for dynamic form , so I am finding no efficient way to raise a form error.Is there any chance that I can raise form validation error from `views.py` file except `forms.py` file. Is not how should I notify (except from form validation) the user that they can not change the title.

Here is my Django `views.py`

```
@login_required
@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
def update_proposal(request, conference_slug, slug):
    conference = get_object_or_404(Conference, slug=conference_slug)
    proposal = get_object_or_404(Proposal, slug=slug, conference=conference)

    if not permissions.is_proposal_author(
            user=request.user, proposal=proposal):
        raise PermissionDenied

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ProposalForm.populate_form_for_update(proposal)
        return render(request, 'proposals/update.html', {'form': form,
                                                         'proposal': proposal})

    # POST Workflow
    form = ProposalForm(conference, data=request.POST)
    if not form.is_valid():
        return render(request, 'proposals/update.html',
                      {'form': form,
                       'proposal': proposal,
                       'errors': form.errors})

    # Valid Form
    if not conference.end_date < datetime.now().date():
        proposal.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
    proposal.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
    proposal.target_audience = form.cleaned_data['target_audience']
    proposal.prerequisites = form.cleaned_data['prerequisites']
    proposal.content_urls = form.cleaned_data['content_urls']
    proposal.speaker_info = form.cleaned_data['speaker_info']
    proposal.speaker_links = form.cleaned_data['speaker_links']
    proposal.status = form.cleaned_data['status']
    proposal.proposal_type_id = form.cleaned_data['proposal_type']
    proposal.proposal_section_id = form.cleaned_data['proposal_section']
    proposal.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('proposal-detail',
                                        args=[conference.slug, proposal.slug]))
```

Here is my `forms.py`:

```
class ProposalForm(forms.Form):

    '''
    Used for create/edit
    '''
    title = forms.CharField(min_length=10,
                            help_text="Title of the proposal, no buzz words!",
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'charfield'}))
    description = forms.CharField(widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=True),
                                  help_text=("Describe your proposal with clear objective in simple sentence."
                                             " Keep it short and simple."))
    target_audience = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=ProposalTargetAudience.CHOICES,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'dropdown'}))
    status = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'dropdown'}),
        choices=ProposalStatus.CHOICES,
        help_text=("If you choose DRAFT people can't the see the session in the list."
                   " Make the proposal PUBLIC when you're done with editing the session."))
    proposal_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'dropdown'}))
    proposal_section = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'dropdown'}))

    # Additional Content
    prerequisites = forms.CharField(
        widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=True), required=False,
        help_text="What should the participants know before attending your session?")
    content_urls = forms.CharField(
        widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=True), required=False,
        help_text="Links to your session like GitHub repo, Blog, Slideshare etc ...")
    speaker_info = forms.CharField(
        widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=True), required=False,
        help_text="Say something about yourself, work etc...")
    speaker_links = forms.CharField(
        widget=PagedownWidget(show_preview=True), required=False,
        help_text="Links to your previous work like Blog, Open Source Contributions etc ...")

    def __init__(self, conference, action="edit", *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProposalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['proposal_section'].choices = _get_proposal_section_choices(
            conference, action=action)
        self.fields['proposal_type'].choices = _get_proposal_type_choices(
            conference, action=action)
        if conference.end_date < datetime.now().date():
            print("This is getting pring have to raise validation error Here")
            raise forms.ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")

    @classmethod
    def populate_form_for_update(self, proposal):
        form = ProposalForm(proposal.conference,
                            initial={'title': proposal.title,
                                     'description': proposal.description,
                                     'target_audience': proposal.target_audience,
                                     'prerequisites': proposal.prerequisites,
                                     'content_urls': proposal.content_urls,
                                     'speaker_info': proposal.speaker_info,
                                     'speaker_links': proposal.speaker_links,
                                     'status': proposal.status,
                                     'proposal_section': proposal.proposal_section.pk,
                                     'proposal_type': proposal.proposal_type.pk, })
        return form
```